# is it better to use one media screen per resolution after all the CSS or is it better to have separate media screens after each section of CSS?

Tags: css

my question is it better to have a single media screen per resolution after all of the CSS code or is it better to have little sections of CSS code and then the relevant media screens? IE:

```
.example 1{ background: #fff; font-size:7rem}
@media screen and (min-width:1921px) {
    .example 1{ background: #ccc; font-size:9rem}
}
     .example 2{ width: 100%; height 50%}
@media screen and (min-width:1921px) {
    example 2{ width: 50%; height 25%}
}
```

----OR-----

```
    .example 1{ background: #fff; font-size:7rem}
    .example 2{ width: 50%; height 25%}
  @media screen and (min-width:1921px) {
        .example 1{ background: #ccc; font-size:9rem}
        .example 2{ width: 50%; height 25%}
    }
```

obviously we are taking about a distance of more than a few lines in a real world example but the question is the same - better to have one large media screen section after all the code, or have media screens after each section, such as the navigation section, the body section, the hero section etc?

Comment: This is an opinion-based question (and thus off-topic). However, the point of media queries and the way CSS is read/interpreted would be better served by the 2nd method, not to mention readability to other devs.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use both approaches, as needed.

If in mobile version the section in question changes a lot I use the second solution, all within a single media screen rule, at the bottom of the style.

If, on the other hand, these are small or very small adjustments and there is no media screen rule at the bottom of my style, I adopt the first approach, a media screen rule immediately after the desktop rules.

Comment: Thanks. So no real danger or benefit either way other than preference?

Comment: No, it is more a matter of order.
When you go to read the code months later it can be a problem. The first solution is certainly more messy if, instead of a single media query, you have several small ones.